# Sharepoint 2013 Search results for Powerpoint files

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have Sharepoint 2013 search site with many documents uploaded in Document Library, I created a custom page with Search results webpart,when i tried to find a powerpoint file named x in search results webpart, it shows result title as "Powerpoint Presentaion" but the actual title is "Some title",Please provide suggestion to bring the powerpoint document title to search results title

Comment: Did you modify anything in the Display Templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint Server 2013 cumulative update published on October 26th 2013 Microsoft changed method of extracting Title and Author managed properties from documents.
 Details are here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2013/10/31/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements.aspx

*Sometimes, people save or upload Word documents or PowerPoint presentations with titles like “Document1.docx” or “Presentation1.pptx”. Before the MetadataExtractor was introduced this title would typically show up as the title in the search results. That was not so good.*

To present a better title for such files in the search results, we use the MetadataExtractor in the content processing pipeline. It searches for a title in the body of Word and PowerPoint files. Currently, if the MetadataExtractor finds a good candidate for a title in the body, it writes the extracted title to the new crawled property MetadataExtractorTitle that is mapped to the managed property Title by default.

Because the title from the crawled property MetadataExtractorTitle has the first priority in the mapping to the managed property Title, there’s a good chance that the titles of Word and PowerPoint files shown in search results are more relevant.

To change it you need to move crawled property "MetadataExtractorTitle" lower in "Title" managed property or even remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to perform an Index Reset after resetting the order of mappings to crawled properties for the Title Managed Property (i.e., moving MetadataExtractorTitle down on the list).